# Angular interceptor Not allowed to upload images

Tags: angular

before making this interceptor, I was able to upload images easily and without errors

```
  intercept(req: any, next: any) {
    let authService = this.injector.get(AuthService);
    let tokenizedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.getToken()}`,
      },
    });
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq);
  }
```

the function in ts

```
  addProduct() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.file);
    formData.append('upload_preset', 'walmart');

    this.http
      .post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload', formData)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.resp = res;
        console.log(this.resp.url);
        this.prod.photos = this.resp.url;
      });
    }
```

Now, after I made this interceptor, I find this error appearing

[image]

[image]

and there is the result without the interceptor

[image]

[image]

I tried to make interceptor to set headers token , but I found it not allowed to upload images , I have tried many solutions but none of them worked for me especially because I am a beginner

thank you

Answer (score 1):

the problem isn't angular related, you should allow CORS on your backend application

Comment: if i comment the interceptor , its working without api

Comment: Yes, because "Authorization" in CORS on your backend application, if you are working with spring boot please read these article https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Answer (score 0):

try this implementation

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Store } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthState } from '../../store/auth.state';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addAuthToken(request));
  }

  addAuthToken(request: HttpRequest<any>) {
    const token = this.authService.getAuthToken();

    return request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain what is different in the changed code and elaborate on why thus would make a difference compared to the original post?

Comment: same problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you include what the image upload code looked like before you refactored it into an interceptor?

Typically for local development you want to use the development proxy (part of the CLI included with the webpack development web server) to proxy paths that would cause CORS issues.

This means for local development you need to use a relative path to the upload resource, capture it in the proxy and forward it to the real absolute url.

The proxy is only for local development, so for deployed builds you want to use the absolute path.

You can use the environment files to define the relative path for local development and absolute path for builds.

proxy.conf.js in the root of your workspace:

```
module.exports [
  {
    context: ['/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload'],
    target: 'https://api.cloudinary.com',
    secure: false,
    logLevel: 'debug',
  }
];
```

In your `angular.json` look for the `"serve"` node and add the proxy config:

```
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "your-app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.js"
          }
```

If you do not have environment files setup, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-application-environments on adding them to your project.

In older Angular CLI projects `environment.ts` is for Development, in newer projects it is for Production. I am assuming this is a newer project.

In your production `environment.ts` file add the config for the absolute URL:

```
export const environment = {
  cloudinaryUrl: 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload'
};
```

In your development `environment.development.ts` file add the relative path:

```
export const environment = {
  cloudinaryUrl: '/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload'
};
```

And now in your interceptor change the http.post to:

```
    this.http
      .post(environment.cloudinaryUrl, formData)
```

**So what does this do?**

This gets past CORS issues when doing local development by proxying the request through the local development proxy. This will only be done for local development. Builds will use the absolute url.

So locally your browser will request:

```
 Browser: http://localhost:4200https:/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload
  V
 Local Dev Proxy: https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload
```

Any request to `/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload` is caught by the proxy server and forwarded to `https://api.cloudinary.com/` bypassing your CORS issues.